# Django update_or_create with potentially null idenitfier

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a function in Django that accepts a post request. If that post request includes an `id`, I want to update that object. If the post request sends a blank/null `id`, I'd like to create a new object and have Django set the ID (primary key) of the model.

Here is what I have:

```
def save_user_roster_to_db():
name = request.data['name']
id = request.data['id'] # this could be null/blank or be an ID
try:
    user_roster = SavedUserRoster.objects.update_or_create(
        id=id,
        defaults={
            "name": name,
        }
    )
    return user_roster.pk
except:
    raise Exception
```

However, this seems to try to assign the blank/null value as the ID when creating a new object. How can I tell Django to set its own ID (which is the primary key) if it's creating a new object?

Comment: If `id` is `None`, django should create a new instance and set the id. If you print `user_roster.pk` do you get `None`?

Comment: Note that `update_or_create` returns a tuple of instance and created (boolean). Accessing `user_roster.pk` might cause an exception to be raised.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `update_or_create` with the id field. Because in the current situation, `id` can have a value of `None`, and the Django model can't create the object with an id of `None`.
So I think you can try like the following.

```
def save_user_roster_to_db():
    name = request.data['name']
    id = request.data['id'] # this could be null/blank or be an ID
    try:
        if id:
            user_roster = SavedUserRoster.objects.get(pk = id).update(name = name)
        else:
            user_roster = SavedUserRoster.objects.create(name = name)
        return user_roster.pk
    except:
        raise Exception
```

Answer (score 0):

Traditionally `id` is auto generated and always unique. In this case replacing None `id` will create exception when you create record for first time.

There are two possible options.

**OPTION 1:**
Create another `unique_identified` i.e username or email.

```
def save_user_roster_to_db():
name = request.data['name']
unique_identified = request.data['unique_identified'] # this could be null/blank or be an ID
user_roster, is_created = SavedUserRoster.objects.update_or_create(
        unique_identified=unique_identified,
        defaults={
            "name": name,
        }
    )
return user_roster.pk
```

**OPTION 2:**

**For Create:**
Get the last `id` from database and add `1` with last id, so that It will be the next `id` value, It will avoid the None exception.

**For Update:**
It will update the existence record against `id`

```
def save_user_roster_to_db():
name = request.data['name']
id = request.data['id'] # this could be null/blank or be an ID
if id is None:
   id = int(MyUserModel.objects.all().last().id)+1
user_roster, is_created = SavedUserRoster.objects.update_or_create(
        id=id,
        defaults={
            "name": name,
        }
    )
return user_roster.pk
```